# Elsevier manuscript template

Tags: templates, journal

Can anyone tell me where I can download a latex manuscript template for computer standards and interfaces journal (Elsevier).

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Few second using Google and less than 10 clicks I found http://www.elsevier.com/journals/computer-standards-and-interfaces/0920-5489/guide-for-authors

Comment: I have seen it and I downloaded the latex template but its one column and the keyword is under not beside the abstract

Comment: Why do you concern yourself with replicating the look of the journal page? You probably don't have access to Elsevier's special font for its journals, so won't be possible to replicate the look perfectly. Just use Elsevier's `elsarticle` document class, as per the recommendation given in @Sigur's comment. It's quite easy, by the way, to specify a two-column format when using the `elsarticle` class.

Comment: Careful: http://thecostofknowledge.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running Debian or Ubuntu, install the texlive-publishers package. The template is called elsarticle.

Two-column layout is an option:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

For the keywords, you need to define

```
\begin{keywords}
keywords go here
\end{keywords}
```

Comment: Hi, i use Kile editor, can i use texlive-publishers package with it ? Thanks for answer. Kind regards.

Comment: I'm not using Kile personally, but I don't see a reason, why it would not work. After all, it's just a text editor, which calls the tex compiler. If you want to use templates from publishers, you just need to use the appropriate document class, which is provided by the texlive-publishers package. That should not depend on the editor in any way.

Comment: I try to find elsevier journal template, the same in the image in this question. i use in my laptop Kile editor and i can't find this template so i have installed texlive ..

Comment: Just to confirm, did you install texlive-publishers? Then you should find the elsevier template at the following position (in Ubuntu and probably also Debian): /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle

Comment: :/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/elsarticle$ ls
elsarticle.cls               That's it ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. And if everything is installed correctly, you should be able to use `\documentclass{elsarticle}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33498/discussion-between-engineer-and-researcher).

Comment: I have used this example http://pastie.org/private/du7zdeesp5bolakxizanoa  pdflatex give me a white paper that contains this text "1. The Model
The main environment modifies that of [? ], into two main dimensions
"