# How can I use Elsevier manuscript template for double column (cas-dc.cls)?

Tags: templates, journal

I want to work on template for [`Journal of Network and Computer Applications`](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-network-and-computer-applications/1084-8045/guide-for-authors) journal. On the [elsdoc](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/documents/elsdoc-1.pdf) at its last page the two-column pre-print format output is as follows:

[image]

Its guide advices to use [els-as-template](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip) that has `cas-dc-template.tex` file, I believe that is the template. But I was not able to compile the `pdflatex cas-dc-template.tex` file in order to  generate this pre-print manuscript example.

When I run `pdflatex cas-dc-template.tex` it gives following errors and exits by unable to generate the pdf file:

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'stm/author/<options>' is unknown and is being
(LaTeX3)        ignored.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.80 \author[<aff no>]{<author name>}[<options>]

?

! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'stm/author/<options>' is unknown and is being
(LaTeX3)        ignored.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.107 \author[<aff no>]{<author name>}[<options>]

?
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \verbatim@start was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.141

?
texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}])
*(Please type a command or say `\end')
*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*
```

When I am able to compile it removing the error lines I get a single-column output as follows:

[image]

Related: [Elsevier manuscript template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226299/elsevier-manuscript-template/226304)

Comment: It is template that has to be filled with data replacing  every `< xxx>`. For example `\author{John Smith}`

Comment: It also gives following error: `! Missing number, treated as zero < l.165 \maketitle`. And it does not generate output pdf as double column :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the working complete-template at overleaf [Elsevier's CAS LaTeX Double-Column Template - Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-double-column-template/hhzpymgjmxfk).

> Elsevier's CAS
> LaTeX Double-Column Template Open as Template View Source View PDF
> Author Elsevier Last Updated 10 months ago License Other (as stated in
> the work) Abstract cas-sc.cls and cas-dc.cls are the two new class
> files created for typesetting Elsevier's journal articles which go
> through Complex Article Service (CAS) workflow.

To [open as template](https://www.overleaf.com/project/new/template/21816?id=28568212&latexEngine=pdflatex&mainFile=cas-dc-template.tex&templateName=Elsevier%E2%80%99s%20CAS%20LaTeX%20Double-Column%20Template&texImage=texlive-full%3A2022.1).